# Extended kalman filter vs online passive-aggressive

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, optimization, kalman-filter, online-algorithms

I was wondering, what are the advantages and disadvantages of **extended Kalman filter** and **online passive-aggressive** algorithm when we use them to train our networks.

I have RBF neural network and I'm trying to decide which method to choose?
Extended Kalman filter is more computationally complicated but it has more details about the model so it can be more accurate and also it is being smart about the noise.

when I compare formula of these two: passive-aggressive ensures the updated classifier $w_{t+1}$ should stay as close as to the previous classifier and also every incoming instance should be classified by the updated classifier correctly. we have the exact same idea in extended Kalman filter 
[image]

so what is the advantage and disadvantage of these two methods? I can't find which one is better.